# Get a number of open sockets in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, diagnostics

I'm trying to log the number of open sockets in my C# server application.
Like the info you could get from "netstat -s":

```
TCP Statistics for IPv4

  Active Opens                        = 22765
  Passive Opens                       = 9316
```

I could parse the result from "netstat".. but if there's a class for it, then why would I..

By the way, with the help of class System.Diagnostics.Process, I could log a number of handles, and threads.
I thought that a socket is a handle, but it seems not..
In my situation, the # of handles was way below # of active connections from netstat.

Any suggestions, advices or answers will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [TcpStatistics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpstatistics.aspx).

For example, the [TcpStatistics.CurrentConnections Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpstatistics.currentconnections.aspx) returns "The number of TCP connections for which the current state is either ESTABLISHED or CLOSE-WAIT."

```
long result = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
                                .GetTcpIPv4Statistics()
                                .CurrentConnections;
```

Comment: by the way, for people who don't want to look up the link... it's System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetTcpIPv4Statistics()